# How to apply optparse to parse a group of parameters

Tags: python, optparse

In python we use optparse to format our CLI parameters. However, I don't know how to apply add_option() on supporting combined or a groups of arguments.

For example:

1) How can my CLI support combined paramters:

eg:

```
python test.py -ah
```

actually, this command can expand to:

```
python test.py -a -h
```

2) How can my CLI support groups parameters:

eg:

```
python test.py -f f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt
```

in this example: space is the separator, we can also define comma also as the separator.

I don't know whether optparse can support.

Comment: optparse is deprecated. See the first example of argparse that uses a group of numbers. https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: Thanks for your prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using optparse for new projects. [According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html):

> Deprecated since version 2.7: The optparse module is deprecated and
>   will not be developed further; development will continue with the
>   argparse module.

The functionality you are looking for is built into [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Test program')
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-v', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-f', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

This yields:

```
$ python parser.py -av -f f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt
Namespace(a=True, f=['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt'], v=True)
```

Comment: @tOmMy No problem! Have you read the page on ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yes, for my reputation is less than 15 and I have already voted your answer's up, the system has recorded this but doesn't show in publicity. Thanks again.